# Can't get Flexigrid to work for table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, flexigrid

I've downloaded flexigrid, and copied the unpacked folder (flexigrid-1.1) to my mvc3 root.

Then added the following to my view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/flexigrid-1.1/js/flexigrid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../flexigrid-1.1/css/flexigrid.css" />
```

This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".flexme").flexigrid();
});
</script>
```

and the table

```
    <table class="flexme">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Kind</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Phones.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var phone in Model.Phones)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => phone.Number);
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => phone.Type);
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But nothing happens, as far as I can see, it finds the .flexigrid() metod, and calls it. I'm new to all this jquery-stuff, so I don't know where to look for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Flexigrid does not work that way.

There are two ways of processing your data:

1. Passing a URL to the plug-in.
2. Passing your records as a Json object directly to the plug-in.

Check this [Flexigrid & Jquery on a MVC3 view with EF4 example](http://chrisblazek.me/2011/06/03/jquery-on-a-mvc3-view-with-ef4-example/).

Comment: I did'nt realize that, thanks for your answer and example-link!